# Gmail's important message markings in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I know I can see my Gmail Priority Inbox in Thunderbird, but what I'd really like is to have those yellow markings beside messages that indicate whether a message is important or not. Is there a way (perhaps an addon) in Thunderbird that I can see those marks?

The yellow marks shown here are what I'm referring to:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Doesn't Thunderbird create an "Important" folder/label?

Comment: @Al Yes. I know I can see my Priority Inbox. What I want is to see all the messages at once, while still having the important ones marked, like in the Everything else section of the Gmail web app.